# sequelize how to connect to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Hi everyone i know that this has been asked before but i cant figure it out so i need some expert help. I am trying to connect to an db i made on db4free and im using node and sequelize

This is my config.js

```
module.exports = {
port: process.env.PORT || 3307,
    db:{
        database: process.env.DB_NAME   || 'databasename',
        user    : process.env.DB_USER   || 'databaseuser',
        password: process.env.DB_PASS   || 'password',
        options :{
            dialect : process.env.DIALECT || 'mysql',
            host    : process.env.HOST    || '127.0.0.1',
            storage : './scoutout.sqlite'
        }
    }
}
```

and in my index.js i create the connection like this

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.db.database,
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.port,
    config.db.options
)
```

When i try to connect i get the following error in my cmd

> throw new Error('Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of
>   v4.0.0');
>         ^ Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

In my config i set the dialect so i don't know where to go from here on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `port` should be part of the `options` passed as 4th parameter, the constructor call is `new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password',{/* named options */});` You are giving the port as the options-object...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have fixed that, now i get a Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307

Comment: Than the server is not listening on `localhost:3307`, or another mechanism is preventing the connection or you are simply passing wrong credentials along...

Comment: You where right, when i do app.listen to that port its working but when i try to do sequelize.sync({force:false})

.then(() => {
    app.listen(config.db.options.port)
    console.log(`Server started on port ${config.db.options.port}`) 
}) it doesnt want to create my tables